# Does Windows 10 hide extensions for known file types by default?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I realize this is a yes or no question, but that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. All versions of Windows, since XP, that I can remember do. But maybe even earlier than that.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so but I just downloaded a W10 Enterprise Evaluation OVA from the microsoft website and file types were not hidden by default.

Comment: Any documentation or link to support the answer? The OP's comment ^^^^ seems to contradict your answer, therefore I'm surprised the answer is accepted.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Author accepted the answer they must in some capacity agree with the answer